# Can poetry and conda consider the dependencies of each other?

Tags: python, package, dependencies, conda

In a python project, I'm using `conda` and `poetry` together. `conda` is used to create the environment and to install `poetry` and `python`. The project dependencies are mainly managed using `poetry`.

However, there are some packages which I would like to install using `conda` as it is more convenient. Such examples include `spyder`, `ipykernel` and packages using CUDA.

The problem is that these packages installed by `conda` of course install dependencies themselves. If I install some other packages using `poetry` afterwards, these dependencies might get replaced by other versions which are again incompatible with the packages installed by `conda`.

Is there any way to have common dependencies which are used by both `conda` and `poetry`?

Listing all dependencies of all children recursively is not an option!